# Error: Overload resolution ambiguity: Text

Tags: android, kotlin

```
package com.example.budgetnator
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import com.budgetnator.name.NavigationItems
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.NavigationBar
import androidx.compose.material3.NavigationBarItem
import androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.NavHostController
import androidx.navigation.compose.NavHost
import androidx.navigation.compose.composable
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController


@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    Scaffold (
        bottomBar = { BottomNavigationBar(navController)}
    ) { innerPadding ->
        Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding), contentAlignment = Alignment.TopStart) {
            NavigationGraph(navController = navController)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun BottomNavigationBar(navController: NavController) {
    val items = listOf(
        NavigationItems.Home,
        NavigationItems.Transactions,
        NavigationItems.Bills,
        NavigationItems.Insights
    )
    NavigationBar {
        val currentRoute = navController.currentDestination?.route
        items.forEach{ item ->
            NavigationBarItem(
                icon = { Icon(painterResource(id = item.icon), item.title) },
                label = { Text(item.title) },
                selected = currentRoute == item.route,
                onClick = {
                    navController.navigate(item.route) {
                        navController.graph.startDestinationRoute?.let {route ->
                            popUpTo(route) { saveState = true }
                        }
                        launchSingleTop = true
                        restoreState = true
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
@Composable
fun NavigationGraph(navController: NavHostController) {
    NavHost(navController, startDestination = NavigationItems.Home.route){
        composable(NavigationItems.Home.route){
            HomeScreen()
        }
        composable(NavigationItems.Transactions.route) {
            TransactionScreen()
        }
        composable(NavigationItems.Bills.route) {
            BillsScreen()
        }
        composable(NavigationItems.Insights.route) {
            InsightsScreen()
        }
    }
}
@Composable
fun CustomTextDisplay(content: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier, textAlign: TextAlign = TextAlign.Start) {
    Box(modifier = modifier, contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        Text(text = content, textAlign = textAlign)
    }
}
@Composable
fun HomeScreen() {
    CustomTextDisplay(
        content = "Home Placeholder",
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        textAlign = TextAlign.Start // Customize alignment if needed
    )
}

@Composable
fun TransactionScreen() {
    CustomTextDisplay(
        content = "Transaction Placeholder",
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center // Customize alignment if needed
    )
}

@Composable
fun BillsScreen() {
    CustomTextDisplay(
        content = "Bills Placeholder",
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        // adjust as needed
    )
}

@Composable
fun InsightsScreen() {
    CustomTextDisplay(
        content = "Insights Placeholder",
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        textAlign = TextAlign.End // Customize alignment if needed
    )
}

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity(){
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background){
                MainScreen()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is when I use the Text function it comes up as Overload resolution ambiguity error.

I have tried changing imports, syncing project with gradle file, I have looked at all my gradle files. I dont know what to do anymore. I did have 7 Text fuctions but i knocked it down to only 2 in my project and it is still doing it the only import that has an effect on it is material3 but the "text" still has a red line under it after i import material3.

Comment: This all looks OK. What's the structure of `NavigationItems`?